# My rejected edit was reedited and still has errors, should I edit it again?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I was about to edit another question and a warning came up that some of my edits have been rejected. And I was suggested that I should review my edit history. Below is my [edit suggestion (link here)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8479508).

Where from this (originally from the OP):

> I'm interesting learning how to customize the Google ads. I know about
>   changing the color, font, width, and height. There appear to be
>   limited choices of fonts and I cannot make the test bold. However, I
>   have seen several sites that have more customization in their ads than
>   this. I want to do the same in Blogger. Does anyone here know how?

I edited to this:

> I'm interested in learning how to customize Google ads.
>
> I know about changing `color`, `font`, `width`, and `height`. It seems there
>   are limited choices of fonts and I cannot make the text **bold**.
>
> However, I have seen several sites that have more customizations in
>   their ads than the mentioned above. I want to do the same in
>   **Blogger**. Does anyone here know how to achieve this?

**Notice that `test` is supposed to be `text` and `there appear` is grammatically incorrect.**
Besides this, I used the code brackets (`) when the OP mentioned CSS properties and highlighted two words.

According to the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), the edit was rejected because:

> [This edit did not correct critical issues with the post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8479508)

S.L. Barth also rejected my edit and [his edit was approved (or didn't need to get approval)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5255948/revisions#rev17210223-95e2-42fd-ab21-261bb290a376) containing this:

> I'm interested in learning how to customize Google ads.
>
> I know about changing the color, font, width, and height. There appear
>   to be limited choices of fonts and I cannot make the test bold.
>
> However, I have seen several sites that have more customization in
>   their ads than this. I want to do the same in Blogger. Does anyone
>   here know how?

So he reused my edit and did not correct the "critical issues" that [Community may have mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8479508), which I am still curious to know which issues are.

I will not edit this question again if the end result is to have another rejection, but I appreciate any insights to the problem here... Even if the errors are considered as minor errors and they won't be corrected.

Answer (score 9):

1. You incorrectly added a tag to the title.
2. The terms you marked as code weren't actually being used as code.  He was using those terms as normal words, not as code.  The fact that a language (especially one not even used/discussed in the question at all) uses those words as keywords is irrelevant.  The use of code formatting there wasn't warranted.
3. "There appear to be [...]" is not grammatically incorrect.  You changed it to something different, but where the original wasn't wrong at all.
4. There's no reason for "bold" to have been bolded.
5. When you added "the mentioned above" you turned a grammatically incorrect statement into another grammatically incorrect statement.  The reviewer editing the post put in a *correct* fix of that statement.
6. There's no reason for "Blogger" to have been bolded.

You're quite right that "test" should have been changed to "text", and the editor didn't apply that change.  I've applied it now.

It's also worth pointing out that when a reviewer rejects and edits they have no control over the rejection reason.  The reason you see is the only possible reason that can be given; there's no way for him to say that many of the edits you made were incorrect, which is why he *actually* rejected your edit, rather than because you missed important changes.  He could provide that reason *when not also editing the post*, but that wasn't what he wanted to do.

Comment: 1) The question is about adsense, it could be about adwords but it's not. 2) They are CSS properties in any case, and highlighting them make them more noticeable, to check what the OP has done or hasn't done. 3) My bad, "there appear" is an uncommon expression, and it's the first time I have seen to be used in that way.

Comment: 4&6) Yes, I could have refrained to use **bold**, I actually would if I knew it was a reason that it could lead to rejection, but it also highlights the question's purpose and where it is being applied. 5) Saying that "there is more stuff somewhere" without mentioning it, only makes a question look poor (and not specific), so I assumed the OP was referring to the properties she mentioned before.
Thanks for editing the errors and being so supportive.

Comment: @Armfoot 1) That doesn't mean you should be editing the tag into the title. 2) The fact that they are CSS properties is *irrelevant*; they're not used to refer to those properties.  Code formatting is not there to highlight content you think is important. 4&6) These *aren't even terms that merits emphasis*.  They aren't important words in this question that should draw attention. 5) Either way, your edit wasn't grammatically correct.  Personally I don't think "this" is ambiguous, I mean what else could you think "this" refers to?  But your edit is missing an object, "the [__] mentioned above".

Comment: There you are wrong, the whole point that made the OP write his/her question was to turn the ads into **bold** which is a special customization that only AdSense Premium users may have access to, and I believe that most **Blogger** users do not qualify to have access to it. So my point was to highlight them in order for people to consider those things before answering... What it makes me sad is that my edit was evaluated mostly by edited text (not considering the question's context) and that I needed to ask this question in order to realize that "the mentioned above" was the rejection reason.

Comment: @Armfoot _"So my point was to highlight them in order for people to consider those things before answering..."_ Until you suggested an edit, the question hadn't even been touched/commented on/edit _for four years._ And even then, there are already two answers, both of which answer with _exactly_ what you're saying is important to keep in mind in the answer: Only premium users can get at the extra customization. So clearly the highlighting of the words wasn't needed. _...in order to realize that "the mentioned above" was the rejection reason"_ That wasn't the _only_ reason for the rejection.

Comment: @Kendra my point is, there may be answers in the future that actually solve the OP's problem, and none of the actual answers refer how to **bold** ads text/change the `font-family` or the relation to **Blogger** (free blogs/domains are harder to get support). So none of them addressed _exactly_ what I described: people now can draw conclusions through the Premium users, but AdSense is evolving, and what may be certain now, may not be in the future. I know my mistake wasn't the _only_ reason, but from what we discussed, it seems the main one...

Comment: @Armfoot Both of the answer addressed custom formatting *in general* because *there isn't anything unique about bolding*.  It would appear, based on the answers that seem to be accepted as correct, that Blogger isn't relevant, which is why it wasn't brought up.  That said, the information is there.  If someone wants to post an answer referencing either of those points, they absolutely can.  That doesn't mean that they need to be bolded in the question though.

Comment: Sure thing Servy, I learned my lesson about **bolding** stuff. Hope my next _**highlightings**_ won't cause so much trouble to so many good people. In fact, following your example, I may dedicate my time to more rewarding actions than editing ;)